# Firefox doesn't show swf file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, flash

Here is my code

```
<div id="sw" style="cursor:pointer" >
<object id="swfobj"  type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</object>
```

And JavaScript part

```
function openfile(filePath) {
        $("#swfobj").attr("data", filePath);
         $("#swfobj").show();
    };
```

I test it in Chrome and Firefox... In Chrome it shows swf when I change data of object(Chrome change it after second click and it problem too, but it show swf wxcept Firefox :D)

In Firefox, I can't see swf anyway... I tried to manually change data, but it doesn't help top... Need your help u suggestions))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the width and height to `1px` each, then set the size to the proper flash size. My guess is that the `swf` is hidden by default. Hidden swfs won't load in some browsers.

Comment: Fine... It works... Thanks a lot)))

And what do you think about Chrome's reaction? Chrome changes swf only after second click(in FF it works perfectly)?

Comment: Are you saying chrome requires you to click to activate the flash? That might be by design.